# how to force spring to return "text/html" instead of "application/json"?

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, response

I have a file attachment plug-in ([AJAX File Upload plugin from Valums](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)) that requires the return json to be of type "text/html". The web application I'm developing utilizes the Spring Framework, which forces the return type to be "application/json". I want the json to return as "text/html". Since the return json is of type "application/json", I get a file download dialog box, which is something the users should not see (the file should upload automatically).

```
@RequestMapping(value="attachmentUpload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, String> attachmentUpload(
        @ModelAttribute("fileUploadFB") @Valid final FileUploadFormBean fileUploadFB,
        BindingResult result,
        SessionStatus sessionStatus,
        HttpServletResponse response) {

    final Map<String, String> resultMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    resultMap.put("success", "true");

    // vain attempts to force text/html; do not work
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");

    return resultMap;
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the contents of the incoming `Accept` header?

Comment: I think it is "text/html"... unless I'm missing something. Is that something I set in the controller or in the plugin?

Comment: The incoming request would specify this.

Comment: where do i set the incoming request? I'm still learning :)

Comment: @user1529955 in your case it's probably the browser/webpage that's making the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I no longer return a hash-map; returning a String along with adding "produces="text/html"" to the RequestMapping works!